# Spring Batch. Call methods with rollbackFor

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, spring-batch

In some batch job, i call a method from a class, that's marked with:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = {
        Fault.class,
        AnotherFault.class
})
public class ...
```

And, when i call this method, and an exception throws i get exception:

```
00:29:25,765 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] (executor-2) Encountered an error executing the step: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

To solve this problem, i try use nested transactions. Jpa don't support nested transactions, so i create dummy class with:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

and call from this dummy class without transactions, my method with transactions and rollbackFor.

Result of this described here: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/locking-problem-in-jdbc-driver-td2174897.html

So, another way to resolve this problem - configure job:

```
<batch:step id="parse-step">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="xmlCommonJob.Reader"
                     processor="xmlCommonJob.Processor"
                     writer="xmlCommonJob.Writer"
                     commit-interval="2"/>
        <batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
            <batch:include class="com.my.common.services.fault.Fault"/>
            <batch:include class="com.my.common.services.fault.AnotherFault"/>
        </batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:next on="FAILED" to="file-failed-step"/>
    <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="file-success-step"/>
</batch:step>
```

all to no avail.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try set <tx:annotation-driven /> in the same xml where you describe the job?

Comment: It is important to indicate that in the xml with job configuration? I set <tx:annotation-driven /> in appContex.xml that's inlude batch.xml.

Comment: I had few problems time ago with tx not correctly managed and put `<tx:annotation/>` in job xml solve the problem; maybe this can help you, not sure

Comment: No. This is not fix for my problem. Maybe more simple to understand information: https://gist.github.com/IRus/cc45db58c5c15e295a12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Batch we shouldn't catch exceptions in steps, for log in database, we should use listener:

```
    <batch:step id="parse-step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="xmlCommonJob.Reader"
                         processor="xmlCommonJob.Processor"
                         writer="xmlCommonJob.Writer"
                         commit-interval="1">
            <batch:skip-policy>
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy" scope="step"/>
            </batch:skip-policy>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="file-failed-step"/>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="file-success-step"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="parseStepExecutionListener"/>
            <batch:listener ref="parseStepSkipListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
```

in bean *parseStepSkipListener* i log exceptions with logger and can save info to database.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to annotate business methods with @Transaction when using Spring Batch.  Spring Batch handles transaction semantics within the framework so adding @Transactional can cause issues.  I'd recommend removing the annotation and letting Spring Batch handle it.

Comment: I can remove @Transaction from my classes, but can't from business methods. I work around, and solve this problem. Soon i describe how i do this.